# Is there any way to make chrome support VP9 and H.265(HEVC) on WebRTC?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, libvpx, h.265

I'm new to WebRTC. As VP9 can decrease the bandwidth, but I don't see any options to choose VP9 with the recent release Chrome 43.0 during a WebRTC session on Windows. The SDP video options don't include VP9 at all. Could someone show me how to enable VP9 for WebRTC? A lot of articles indicate VP9 has been ready.

Another question, is there a way to add H.265 encoder/decoder to the system and let WebRTC stack of Chrome be aware of it?

Comment: You cannot add encoders to chrome that it does not natively support. Even if you enable Vp9 on the browser, you will have to see if you can modify the SDP to include it as an option(edit it manually before setting it as the localdescription and then sending it to the peer) but that may not work as the underlying parser could not support utilizing that encoder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable Chrome for VP9 by passing the flag,

```
--enable-webrtc-vp9-support
```

To enable flags on Windows,

1. Right click on Chrome
2. Select "Properties"
3. At the end of the target line, add the above flag, so it will be running like, `chrome.exe --enable-webrtc-vp9-support`

As far as I know, the HEVC/H.265 RTP payload packetization/parsing is not implemented yet for WebRTC.